# How to sava data on mysql using sequelize, express and pinia?

Tags: mysql, vue.js, express, sequelize.js, pinia

I have this web app which I want to save email and password (it is a create account page). I'm using Pinia in order to manage these data. Just like below:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useUsersStore = defineStore("usersStore", {
    state: () => ({
        users: [],
    }),

    actions: {
        createUser(user) {
            console.log("Creating account!");
            return this.users.push(user);

        },
    },
});
```

On my Vue component, this is the function passing the data from form to pinia:

```
const submitForm = () => {
    usersStore.createUser({
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value,
    });
};
```

I have already settled my mysql database:

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");

const sequelize = new Sequelize("pia", "root", "123456789", {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
});

sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log("#####  Connected");
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log("#####    Error");
    });

module.exports = sequelize;
```

Server running:

```
const express = require("express");
const User = require("./User");

const port = 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.listen(port, console.log(`#####   Server running on ${port}`));
```

```
const db = require("./db");
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

const User = db.define("users", {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
});

User.sync();

module.exports = User;
```

and the route:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const User = require("./User");

router.post("/newuser", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { email } = req.body;
        await User.create({
            email,
        });
        console.log("200 OK");
    } catch {
        console.log("Error");
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

The point is... I can't pass the email and password to the database... no ideia how to do it,  already read the docs but no success :(

Comment: Your question is missing debugging details and specific problem. Saying you can't do something isn't a good technical description of a problem. Is there an error, or specific issue? There's many steps between the user entering their information and committing that information to the database. Can you narrow it down at all? You haven't shown how your frontend calls `/newuser`. What debugging have you done? Putting console.logs everywhere you should be able to narrow it down, and at a minimum figure out if the problem is at least frontend or backend.